# Open up Windows Form from within another Windows Form and detect button click

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm learning how to use Windows Forms currently. I have a main Windows Form (MainForm) that controls everything. At a certain point during execution, I want to open up another Windows Form that contains a Listbox (ListboxForm) and a button (DoneButton) that indicates when the user is done with ListboxForm. I've managed to get ListboxForm to show up, but I'm unsure of how to make MainForm wait and continue execution after the user presses DoneButton.

Right now, when ListboxForm pops up and the user clicks DoneButton, ListboxForm is still displayed and nothing happens. I'm unsure of why this is happening - I have a this.close in the button code for DoneButton.

Here's my code for ListboxForm:

```
public partial class ListboxForm : Form
{
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();

    public UpdateGhubAndWebConfigForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _items.Add("Option 1");
        _items.Add("Option 2");
        _items.Add("Option 3");

        listBox1.DataSource = _items;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    // This is for 'DoneButton'
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoggingProvider.Log.Info("ListboxForm DoneButton clicked with index: " + listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());

        DoStuff();

        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    public static void DoStuff() { }
}
```

and MainForm opens/creates a ListboxForm like this:

```
if(displayListboxForm == true)
{
    var listboxForm = new ListboxForm();
    listboxForm.ShowDialog();

    // Now I want MainForm to wait until the user clicks DoneButton in ListboxForm
    MessageBox.Show("User has selected an option from ListboxForm");
}
```

Comment: How is the ListBoxForm triggered from the MainForm? Can you post the entire method? I don't see anything unusual that would cause the ListBoxForm to stay displayed after the done button is clicked.

Comment: It's contained within a Task. The bottom of the post shows the chunk that triggers the ListboxForm.

Comment: is the button click event for DoneButton actually firing? Does your Log entry get created?

Comment: No, the click event is not firing.

Comment: Verify in your ListBoxForm's designer that the DoneButton's click event is actually handled by the button1_Click method.

Comment: @Riv Where would I find that? I'm looking at ListboxForms designer properties and I don't see an option/setting to select the method.

Comment: Ah, maybe in Events? I see that the ListboxForm only has 'Load: Form1_Load" while the DoneButton only has 'Click: button1_Click' set.

Comment: bit old, but it still applies https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984320(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I think it may be related to the events not being sent. I copied over ListboxForm from another project and it seems that has caused the bindings to become undone (they're still bound properly in the source project). I'll set those up properly and see how that goes.

Comment: yes copying over the form would cause anomalies. Once you set them up properly and the event gets triggered, let me know if you still need help making it a modal of the MainForm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen to any event of a form, you need to subscribe to that delegate, basically, your MainForm creates an instance of your ListboxForm that is the one that has the Button you want to click. Put the visibility of the button public

```
public Button button1....
```

then from your method subscribe to the event

```
if(displayListboxForm == true)
{
    var listboxForm = new ListboxForm();
    //subscribing to the click event
    listboxForm.button1.Click += YourMethod;
    listboxForm.ShowDialog();

    // Now I want MainForm to wait until the user clicks DoneButton in ListboxForm
    MessageBox.Show("User has selected an option from ListboxForm");
}

public void YourMethod(EventArgs e)
{
   //your logic here when the button is clicked
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm a little confused however. How does your 'public Button button1' work exactly? How does that link up to the actual button displayed in ListboxForm. The button in ListboxForm has the name 'DoneButton' (I can find it via Intellisense). Is there a way to connect 'public Button button1' to 'DoneButton'?

Comment: @Roka545 that is the DoneButton, I took the name from the code you put, but that should be generated as a partial class where all variables that you drop on your designer are generated, change its access to public